# Is there an etymological link between the words "asymptote" and "asymptomatic"?

Tags: etymology

The words

- "[asymptote](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/asymptote)" (used in mathematics), and
- "[asymptomatic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/asymptomatic)" (used in medicine),

have a large number of letters in common.  So:

> **Question**:  Is there an etymological link between the words "asymptote" and "asymptomatic"?

And, of course, if so, what is it?

Comment: OED says they both derive from Gr. *σύµπτωµα* chance, accident, mischance, disease. Leading to *συµπίπτειν* - to fall together, fall upon, happen to, and *ἀσύµπτωτος* - not falling together.

Comment: **asymptote (n.)** 
"straight line continually approaching but never meeting a curve," 1650s, from Gk. asymptotos "not falling together," from a- "not" + syn "with" + ptotos "fallen," verbal adjective from piptein "to fall" (see petition). Related: Asymptotic.
**[symptomatic](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=symptomatic&allowed_in_frame=0) (adj.)** 
1690s, from Fr. symptomatique or directly from L.L. symptomaticus, from symptomat-, stem of symptoma (see symptom). Related: Symptomatical (1580s).
**asymptomatic (adj.)** 
"without symptoms," 1856, from a-, privative prefix, + symptomatic.

Comment: So the answer is, yes, there is an etymological link but 'asymptote' is a more recent mathematical technical term, and 'symptom' is much older technical medical term and much further removed from its literal meaning.

Answer (score 5):

Gk. *piptein* “to fall” is the common factor between *[asymptote](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=asymptote&searchmode=none)* (Gk. *asymptotos* “not falling together”) and *a[symptomatic](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=symptomatic&searchmode=none)* (*a* + *sympiptein* “to befall”).

(Culled from *Online Etymology Dictionary*.)

Answer (score 2):

[Asymptote](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/asymptote)

> origin C17: from mod. L. asymptota (linea) ‘(line) not meeting’, from Gk asumptōtos ‘not falling together’.

[Symptom](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/symptom)

> origin ME synthoma, from med. L., based on Gk sumptōma ‘chance, symptom’, from sumpiptein ‘happen’; later influenced by Fr. symptome.

So, they're not really related, other than both being derived from Latin via Greek, and sharing the Greek prefix "sum" ("with").

- *asymptote* comes from 17th Century mathematics, *symptom* from medieval times
- *asymptote* is derived from the Greek [**ἀσύμπτωτος**](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=a%29su/mptwtos&la=greek&can=a%29su/mptwtos0&prior=a%29su/mpotos) (not falling in), while *symptom* comes from the Greek [**σύμπτωμα**](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=su/mptwma&la=greek&can=su/mptwma0) (something that happens, a chance, an occurrence)

Comment: Hmm. [FumbleFingers' comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/89855/is-there-an-etymological-link-between-the-words-asymptote-and-asymptomatic#comment178288_89855) quoting OED directly contradicts this.

Comment: The similarity of 'falling in' and 'happening' seems to me non-coincidental (pun intended).